# iframe is not working in ionic app Android

Tags: ionic-framework, iframe-app

I developed an app with ionic framework for both iOS and Android. There is no problem in iOS.  But, iframe is not showing anything in Android device although it works very well in iOS and browser.
Here is sample iframe I used.

```html
<div class="card">
     <div class="item item-divider">
        Number of students in primary education
       </div>
      <div class="item item-text-wrap">
   <p><iframe width="100%" height="325" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" src="http://www.google.com/publicdata/embed?ds=d5bncppjof8f9_&amp;ctype=l&amp;strail=false&amp;bcs=d&amp;nselm=h&amp;met_y=se_prm_enrl&amp;scale_y=lin&amp;ind_y=false&amp;rdim=region&amp;idim=country:AFG&amp;ifdim=region&amp;hl=en_US&amp;dl=en_US&amp;ind=false"></iframe></p>   
        </div>
     </div>
```

Thank you :)

Comment: Which version of android platform are you using? (`cordova platform list`) Are there any errors in remote developer console?

Comment: Any errors in developer console? Since Cordova 5.0 most people need the cordova-whitelist-plugin: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist

Comment: Thank you KateMihalikova.  Device is 4.2.2 and in cordova platform list, android 4.0.0.  There is no problem in developer console.

Comment: Thank you Mark Veenstra.  You're great!  After installing, it is worked.  :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using cordova 5.0 or above then add the white-list plugin.

```
ionic plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist.git
```